# Progress Bar Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am wanting to create a progress bar which follows the path of the code outlined in my jquery example:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42a7s5nt/13/

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(85, 161);
context.lineTo(245, 161);
context.quadraticCurveTo(310, 145, 310, 90);
context.quadraticCurveTo(300,20,230,20);
context.lineTo(85, 20);
context.quadraticCurveTo(20,34,20,90);
context.quadraticCurveTo(35,160,85,160);
context.lineWidth = 30;
context.strokeStyle = '#db1e33';
context.stroke();
```

How would I go about animating this bar as a percentage/progress bar? It starts bottom left as red and works it way around anti-clockwise. I have seen various examples but I am unable to implement them as they are based on radial examples using pi or straight lines.

I essentially want to animate the draw path based on a percentage.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/Aapn8/ - I have seen this example and it does what I need but it's not the correct shape/styling.

Comment: People use circles because the parameter is easy to handle : a number in [0 ; 2*PI]. In your case, first thing you should do is to be able to draw your bar for any percentage in [0;100]. This would involve computing the length along the various curves... not so easy...
 I made an approximation by clipping with a circle the drawing of the green part. If you're interested i might explain it. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/42a7s5nt/15/  ( set the debug var to true to see the clipping circle ).

Comment: @GameAlchemist This was the example I was trying to implement initially but I was unsure where to plot the circle initially because I knew it was more of a radial progress bar. Great working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GameAlchemist has a good simplifying idea to use semi-circles on each side instead of Q-Curves.  That's because the circumference of a circle is easily computed: 2*PI*radius. The circumference of a Q-Curve is much more difficult to compute: plot 100+ points on the curve and measure total distance covered by those points.

In turn, you can easily calculate the total length of your path.  Total length is critical if you want to have your progress bar display evenly when going from 0% to 100%.

The idea is to display as much of the 2 lines and 2 semi-circles as necessary to represent the percent-complete.

[image][image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qbapv8ws/

```
// calculate the total path length
var PI=Math.PI;
var radius=50;
var circumference=2*PI*radius;
var lineLeft=100;
var lineRight=200;
var lineWidth=lineRight-lineLeft;
var totalLength=circumference+lineWidth*2;
```

You can then draw your progress bar using these calculations plus a percentage-complete:

```
var lineTop=100;
var lineBottom=lineTop+radius*2;
var lineVertMiddle=(lineTop+lineBottom)/2;


function draw(pct){
    var pctLength=totalLength*pct;

    // draw complete path in red
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lineLeft,lineBottom);
    ctx.lineTo(lineRight,lineBottom);
    ctx.arc(lineRight,lineVertMiddle,radius,PI/2,-PI/2,true);
    ctx.lineTo(lineLeft,lineTop);
    ctx.arc(lineLeft,lineVertMiddle,radius,PI*3/2,PI/2,true);
    ctx.stroke();

    // draw percent path in green
    ctx.strokeStyle='green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lineLeft,lineBottom);

    // bottom line counterclockwise
    if(pctLength>0){
        var x=Math.min(pctLength,lineWidth);
        ctx.lineTo(lineLeft+x,lineBottom);
        pctLength-=x;
    }
    // right arc
    if(pctLength>0){
        var sweepAngle=Math.min(PI,PI*pctLength/(circumference/2));
        ctx.arc(lineRight,lineVertMiddle,radius,PI/2,PI/2-sweepAngle,true);
        pctLength-=Math.min(pctLength,circumference/2);
    }
    // top line
    if(pctLength>0){
        var x=Math.min(pctLength,lineWidth);
        ctx.lineTo(lineRight-x,lineTop);
        pctLength-=x;
    }
    // left arc
    if(pctLength>0){
        var sweepAngle=Math.min(PI,PI*pctLength/(circumference/2));
        ctx.arc(lineLeft,lineVertMiddle,radius,PI*3/2,PI*3/2-sweepAngle,true);
    }   

    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the example I was trying to implement @markE. I knew Pi was a better example of the arc but I was unsure how to initially implement. An exceptional example!